Laravel Auditing error on setting database connection
I want to save audit logs on a different database connection, apart from my Laravel app's database.
on config/audit.php I have set the database name I want to use,
'drivers' => [
    'database' => [
        'table'      => 'audits',
        'connection' => 'adviserhub_audit_logs',
    ],
],

then ran php artisan migrate but it returns an error
InvalidArgumentException 
Database connection [database_name] not configured.

I don't understand why it's returning an error.
Here is my database setting on mysql
Default collation: utf8mb3_general_ci
Default characterset: utf8mb3

What's in your  config/database.php? are you sure 'adviserhub_audit_logs' is defined in connections?

adviserhub_audit_logs is the database name.
Do I need to make a connection config for this database I wan to use?
`

Of course, how does the system know where to connect?

Sorted! I added a connection setting on config/database.php for adviserhub_audit_logs 
